# using strtotime or Timestamp in mysql Select

Tags: mysql, strtotime

I'm trying to select authors where the date in their record, pubMonth + pubYear, has passed. I've tried several combinations of WHERE statements but none of them are eliminating the records that are larger than $today, and that is the only problem.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$today = strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));
mysql_select_db($xxxxxxxxxx, $xxxxxxx);
$query_rsfindAuth = "SELECT Author.FirstName, Authors.level2, Authors.pubMonth, Authors.pubYear 
FROM Authors 
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Author.pubMonth+Author.pubYear) 
    < $today) AND level2 = 'Nature'
```

But I've tried each of these, 'cause I'm kinda shooting in the dark.

```
WHERE ((Authors.pubMonth+Authors.pubYear )  < " . $today . ")   AND level2 = 'Nature'
WHERE (Authors.pubMonth+Authors.pubYear )   < $today        AND level2 = 'Nature'
WHERE " . strtotime(pubMonth.pubYear ) . "      < $today)       AND level2 = 'Nature'
WHERE pubMonth+pubYear)             < $today)       AND level2 = 'Nature'
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pubMonth+pubYear )    < $today)       AND level2 = 'Nature'
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(pubMonth+pubYear )     < " . $today . ")   AND level2 = 'Nature'
```

As always, thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS('-', gradYear, gradMonth, '01')) < '$today'
```

Comment: Hi Explosion Pills. Thanks for responding. It is still giving me records from June of 2014 as well as the expected one from June of 2012.

Comment: @AllThisOnAnACER can you create a sample on sqlfiddle.net?

Comment: After looking at sqFiddle, I'm not comfortable with it and would likely confuse the issue further. Thanks for the suggestion, though.